# facing issue while parsing xml with xpath compile

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have just started learning xml parsing through java. I am stuck with the below issue for a quite some time now and need some help.

I have an xml document which look something like this(just the small representation of a big xml document).

```
`<shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item id="2">
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>`
```

I am trying to find payload when attribute 'id="2"'present.

Below is the regex I am using with xpath compile:

> XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[@id=\"2\"]");

The issue:
This regular expression gives me

```
`<item id="2">
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>`
```

When I only need :

`<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<note>Special Edition</note>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>10.90</price>`

How do I achieve this result?

This question can be really silly as I am just trying to learn xml parsing in java. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note, an XPath expression is not a regular expression. It's a good idea to learn the correct terminology because it will help people understand your questions.

Comment: Sure.I am really sorry for that. As I've mentioned, just starting with this. I will keep this in mind (learned something new:) )

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to get only the subnodes:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[@id=\"2\"]/*");
```

**Result:**

```
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<note>Special Edition</note>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>10.90</price>
```

This expression returns all children of all `<item>` elements with the attribute value `@id` = `2`.

Comment: Hi zx485, this definitely helped but the problem is "id = 2" can be present in other tags as well. like `<temp id="2">this is a test</temp>`. Earlier, this used to get detected in the query. Now after adding /*, I do not get this result. I only get where there are child nodes available.

Comment: nvm, I figured it out. Thank you so much zx485.